# Indentify unused grails domain classes

Tags: grails

I have to identify all domain classes which are not used in my grails application the project has approximately 300+ domain classes, is there any(plugin) way to identify the domain which are currently not used

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any plugin or tool that will do this for you. It's going to be up to you to determine if a domain class is used. Some ways to approach this would be:

1. Does it exist persisted in your data store? If not, it may not be used.
2. Remove it from the system. Do all the tests pass?

Aside from auditing the code (searching for domain classes by name) there isn't going to be a definitive way to determine this.